# Reading a json file into a RDD (not dataFrame) using pyspark

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following file: test.json >

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "A green door",
    "price": 12.50,
    "tags": ["home", "green"]
}
```

I want to load this file into a RDD. This is what I tried:

```
rddj = sc.textFile('test.json')
rdd_res = rddj.map(lambda x: json.loads(x))
```

I got an error:

> Expecting object: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

I don't completely understand what does `json.loads` do.

How can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39430868/reading-json-file-in-pyspark

Comment: The JSON format is not so great for processing with Spark textfile as it will try and process line-by-line, whereas the JSONs cover multiple lines. If you can access your JSON data in the JSON lines format (each json object is "flattened" to a single line, that will work. Alternatively, you can keep the data in the format above and use sc.wholeTextFiles. This returns a key/value rdd, where key is the filename and value is the file content. Then you can process by wrapping the json.loads above into a function which you apply via mapPartitions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to read json with schema in spark dataframes/spark sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39355149/how-to-read-json-with-schema-in-spark-dataframes-spark-sql)

Comment: This is actually not a dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`textFile` reads data line by line. Individual lines of your input are not syntactically valid JSON.

Just use json reader:

```
spark.read.json("test.json", multiLine=True)
```

or (not recommended) whole text files

```
sc.wholeTextFiles("test.json").values().map(json.loads)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Looks like a fair approach. However, I was using spark 1.6 which does not have the spark module. What worked for me was:
rddj = hiveContext.jsonFile("input file path").

Comment: does spark.read.json load data into a RDD or into Dataframe? I have a huge json, approx ~1TB, so it needs to be loaded into a RDD

Comment: @FemnDharamshi It loads into a Dataframe

Comment: I went for the second option, as the first one creates a dataframe, not an RDD.