# spark read schema from separate file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have my data in HDFS and it's schema in MySQL. I'm able to fetch the schema to a DataFrame and it is as below :

```
col1,string
col2,date
col3,int
col4,string
```

How to read this schema and assign it to data while reading from HDFS?

I will be reading schema from MySql . It will be different for different datasets . I require a dynamic approach , where for any dataset I can fetch schema details from MySQL -> convert it into schema -> and then apply to dataset.

Comment: I guess this is relevant to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39355149/how-to-read-json-with-schema-in-spark-dataframes-spark-sql/39355790

Comment: You can create a dataframe with the data of which schema you need. Create a variable with schema like `schemadf =df.schema` and while creating a new one just pass this variable like `newDf = spark.createDataFrame(schemadf,data)`

Comment: Hi, as i will be reading schema from MySql . It will be different for different datasets . I require a dynamic approach , where for any dataset I can fetch schema details from MySQL -> convert it into schema -> and then apply to dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in pyspark function [_parse_datatype_string](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/15557a7d05d9a12dffcf82daa219c0cdb9cba39e/python/pyspark/sql/types.py#L760):

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import _parse_datatype_string

df = spark.createDataFrame([
  ["col1,string"],
  ["col3,int"],
  ["col3,int"]
], ["schema"])

str_schema = ",".join(map(lambda c: c["schema"].replace(",", ":") , df.collect()))
# col1:string,col3:int,col3:int

final_schema = _parse_datatype_string(str_schema)

# StructType(List(StructField(col1,StringType,true),StructField(col3,IntegerType,true),StructField(col3,IntegerType,true)))
```

`_parse_datatype_string` expects a DDL-formatted string i.e: `col1:string, col2:int` hence we need first to replace `,` with `:` then join all together seperated by comma. The function will return an instance of `StructType` which will be your final schema.

Comment: @ Alexandros  while passing it as Schema im getting Error :  TypeError: 'StructType' object is not callable
Code -     str_schema = ','.join(map(lambda c: ':'.join([c["col_name"],c["col_type"]]), df_schema_sql.collect()))                                                                                      
final_schema = _parse_datatype_string(str_schema) ;                                                        
dataframe = sc.read.parquet('/path').schema(final_schema)

Comment: @ Alexandros  - also type(final_schema)     : <class 'pyspark.sql.types.StructType'>

Comment: @isha the code that you posted if different that the one I posted. In the initial question there only column schema a string, has that changed? Also please make sure that final_schema is a valid StructType by printing it out. Finally change the call to `sc.read.schema(final_schema).parquet('/path')` because parquet(...) will return a dataframe instance and you need to set schema before that. The error is saying exactly that, that there is no `schema()` function found for the dataframe

Comment: @Alexandors - Thanks a lot . it's working perfectly fine now, with change in schema() function call.

Comment: great I am glad @isha