# Best practice for writing a facade over JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I've got a JSON file I'm working with. I'll mostly be doing data transformations on the stuff in the  `data` property. I'd like to be able to easily do stuff like `.filter` to `restaurantName` and `joined` without the hassle of delving into the JSON structure each time.

```
const data = [
  {
    position: 1,
    title: "Queues Near You",
    data: [
      [
        {
          restaurantName: "Tonkotsu",
          joined: false,
        },
        {
          restaurantName: "BurgerVille",
          joined: false,
        },
      ],
    ],
  },
  {
    position: 2,
    title: "Restaurants Near You",
    data: [
      [
        {
          restaurantName: "Seoreni",
          joined: false,
        },
        {
          restaurantName: "Jinmu",
          joined: false,
        },
      ],
    ],
  },
];
```

So I decided to make a facade `toRestaurantArray`, that returns an array of arrays out of `restaurantName` i.e `[["Tonkotsu","BurgerVille"], ["Seoreni", "Jinmu"]]`, that I can use much easier. Then I created a `fromRestaurantArray` that recreates the JSON structure from this new array.

Am I approaching this problem the right way with the `to` and `from` functions? If not, what's a better route, and if I am, how can I refactor the code below in terms of logic (ignore the `any` types)? I can tell the code in `fromRestaurant` that just repeatedly loops over the JSOn structure is terrible but am unsure on a better approach.

```
 
type RestaurantDetails = {
  restaurantName: string;
  joined: boolean;
};
 
type Restaurant = {
  position: number;
  title: string;
  data: Array<Array<RestaurantDetails>>;
};
 
function* zip(arrayOne: any[], arrayTwo: any[]) {
  const len = arrayOne.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    yield [arrayOne[i], arrayTwo[i]];
  }
}
 
// Expected output is to return just the list inside data
const toRestaurantsArray = (initialRestaurantsData: Restaurant[]) => {
  const allRestaurantNames: any = [];
  for (const eachRestaurantData of initialRestaurantsData) {
    const [restaurants] = eachRestaurantData.data;
    const restaurantNames = restaurants.map(
      ({ restaurantName }) => restaurantName
    );
    allRestaurantNames.push(restaurantNames);
  }
  return allRestaurantNames;
};
 
const fromRestaurantsArray = (
  restaurantsArray: any[],
  initialRestaurantsData: any[]
) => {
  const reconstructedRestaurantsData: any = [];
  for (const [restaurantNestedArray, eachRestaurantData] of zip(
    restaurantsArray,
    initialRestaurantsData
  )) {
    const dataProperty: any = [];
    for (const [restaurantName, eachRestaurantsInnerData] of zip(
      restaurantNestedArray,
      eachRestaurantData.data[0]
    )) {
      dataProperty.push({
        ...eachRestaurantsInnerData,
        restaurantName: restaurantName,
      });
    }
    const myTotal = { ...eachRestaurantData, data: dataProperty };
    reconstructedRestaurantsData.push(myTotal);
  }
  return reconstructedRestaurantsData;
};
 
const restoArray = toRestaurantsArray(data);
const filteredArray = restoArray.filter((arr:string[]) => arr.includes("Tonkotsu"))
const reconstructedArray = fromRestaurantsArray(filteredArray, data);
console.log(reconstructedArray)
```

Comment: I don't think the drop in performance is worth saving a few extra keystrokes when transforming the data.

Comment: Terminology note: what you have there is a **JavaScript object**, not a "JSON object".

Comment: @caTS What are you referring to specifically? You mean dont refactor the `to` and `from` functions? Or dont even use `to` and `from` functions?

Comment: You're actively transforming to and from a specific structure just to transform it a little. Why do that every time you need to transform it? You could instead transform the original structure.

Comment: @caTS My example only uses `filter` on the object. But I’d like to perform many operations on the stuff in the `data` property . If I have multiple functions that directly manipulate the structure e.g filtering by removal, filtering by length of restaurant name, then id have 1. repetitive code that re-delves into the `data` portion of the object each time and 2. functions that are tightly coupled with with the object, making it difficult to refactor if i refetch data from a similar api with slightly different structure

Comment: @caTS I might have been unclear. I am not trying to re-transform the original structure multiple times with different functions. Whenever I invoke a function that manipulates `data`, I would like to create a copy of the object, **but** with transformations done on the stuff in `data`. e.g two buttons with onClick handlers, the first button filters the original object by removal and the second button filters the original object by restaurant length name. These two operations are independent

Answer (score 0):

I cannot offer a direct solution to your question.

JSON formatting notwithstanding, I think what you are attempting to do is similar to what [Firebase's query language](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) and [other database products](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39355790/3971390) do with JSON.

Here's an article entitled *[Jolt: JSON to JSON Transformation Library](https://medium.com/@aleemraja95/jolt-json-to-json-transformation-library-71e118459198)*.

Not really my area, but my understanding is that these technologies rely on meta data to index the "searchable" parts of a JSON blob. I once had a passing interest in JSON schemas but, so far, haven't had a practical need for implementing one myself.

Your question here reminded me a bit of schemas and made me think about a practical use case for them beyond validation.

(Back in the day, I use to regularly transform XML documents in a similar manner to what you are attempting to do with JSON. There are specialized libraries for transforming XML.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Jolt does look like it fits well with my usecase, I'll toss you the bounty i don't get another answer soon